# How to make GUI size fixed size in every computer using powershell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I have an GUI, I want to make the size of the GUI will be the same no matter size of the computer. I tried this, but when I execute in the bigger display, the size of the GUI is bigger, if I execute in small display, the GUI become small size.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()


$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '1085,650'
$Form.text                       = "FORM"
$Form.BackColor                  = "#f6f6f6"
$Form.AutoSize                   = $true
$Form.FormBorderStyle            = "FixedDialog"
$Form.MaximizeBox                = $false
$Form.startposition              = "centerscreen"

$Groupbox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox1.height                = 592
$Groupbox1.width                 = 1047
$Groupbox1.text                  = "INFO"
$Groupbox1.Font                  = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,9'
$Groupbox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(18,14)
$Groupbox1.AutoSize              = $true
$Groupbox1.ForeColor             = "#032d5d"

$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.BackColor               = "#136aa4"
$Button1.text                    = "OK"
$Button1.width                   = 70
$Button1.height                  = 27
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(960,57)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Button1.AutoSize                = $true
$Button1.ForeColor               = "#ffffff"
```

Comment: This is really not a PowerShell code specific issue. Your scenario would be the same for an GUI created in any language. It's all in your form code, not in your PowerShell code. Pixel / resolution density per display will always be different, per what the user set their screen to. You can change that in code, but you'll tick off your users. Especially users who are visually impaired, thus must have larger font and GUI for it to be usable. You can just set it for what you like, you have to set if for user expectations / needs or allow them to be able to resize it.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying autosize and autoscaling off maybe?

```
$form.AutoScale = $false
$form.AutoSize = $false
```

You have to be careful with this though, you run the risk of the form being unreadable on very high resolution displays.